# Grails 3 Upgrade - could not extract ResultSet

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

Im getting the following error after changing multiple mixins to traits as part of a grails 3 upgrade from 2.2.

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

The error happens here

if (man.names)

names is a hasMany property of type MansNameEnt on the ManEnt, the join table exists in the database. Not sure why this is breaking now?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you pls comment on how this was fixed?

Comment: @JohnTheBeloved I explain the fix in my answer.

Comment: Alright, Thanks, Appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I switched on the hibernate logging, I could see hibernate was generating the wrong join table name. So in the mapping of the entity class i explicitly set the join table i.e

names joinTable: [name:"join_table_name", key: "key", column: "column"]